# How do I access an Array Value using it's Key in a view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I've been working on a method to email the users data to themselves and I'm having trouble printing data in the view. I can access all the data in bulk but I would like to format it so it displays within a HTML table for the user.

Model:

```
    function getEmailData($usersid){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('symptom');
    $this->db->where('userid', $usersid);
    $symptomState = $this->db->get();
    $result = $symptomState->result_array();

    return $result;
}

function getEmailBMData($usersid){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bowelmovement');
    $this->db->where('userid', $usersid);
    $bmState = $this->db->get();
    $result = $bmState->result_array();

    return $result;
}
```

Controller:

```
    function sendDataAsEmail(){
    $uid = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $uname = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $uemail = $this->input->post('email_data');

    $data = array(
         'userName'=> $uname,
        );

    $data['symptomData'] = $this->poomonitormodel->getEmailData($uid);
    $data['bmData'] = $this->poomonitormodel->getEmailBMData($uid);
    $data['symptomCount'] = $this->poomonitormodel->getTotalSymptomCount($uid);
    $data['bmCount'] = $this->poomonitormodel->getTotalBMCount($uid);

    var_dump($data);

    $contents = $this->load->view('pooemail.php',$data,TRUE);

    $this->email
        ->from('#', '#')
        ->to($uemail)
        ->subject('#')
        ->message($contents)
        ->set_newline("\r\n")
        ->set_mailtype('html');

    $this->email->send();
}
```

View:

```
<p>
    <?php foreach($symptomData as $data){
                        foreach($data as $nestdata){
                            echo $nestdata;
                        };
                    };?>
                </p>
                <p>
                <?php foreach($bmData as $bmdata){
                        foreach($bmdata as $nestbmdata){
                            echo $nestbmdata;
                        };
                 };?>
</p>
```

Currently `echo $nestdata` outputs the data as a complete string like this, but I would like to access a single attribute like `$nestdata['symptomdate']`:

462016-04-1402:00burningOesophagus7vomitting    562016-04-1405:00tinglingGallBladder3vomitting  662016-04-1410:00shootingSmallIntenstine8vomitting  1362016-04-2016:47crampGallBladder1Gurgling Noise   1462016-04-2016:58tinglingRectum1Strange tingling sensation in the raer 1962016-04-2017:41crampIleum2Cramping   2062016-04-2017:42crampAnus7It whistles 2162016-04-2017:42crampRectum7It also whistles

But I would like to access a specific value so that I can put each bit of data into a table data cell so it's easier to read for the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in `$data` will be the name of the var in the view. So, `$data['symptomCount']` in the controller will be accessed as `$symptomCount` in the view.

What you do with it depends on its type. If `$symptomCount` is an object (class) then $x = `$symptomCount->some_property`. If it is an array - `$symptomCount['some_index']`

Iterate them like so

```
foreach($symptomData as $symptom){
   echo $symptom['symptomdate'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can now access the symptom data one by one using echo $symptomData[0]['symptomdate']; how can I iterate over this so I don't have to go through each index one by one like 0,1,2 etc?